# python request url with user ip

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrape, m3u8

I'm running this script in server trying to request m3u8 file but i have to request m3u8 file with user IP address i know how to get user IP with `os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]` but struggling where to put it and how to request

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2,urllib,re
import os
#os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
#print os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]

url='http://www.atv.com.tr/webtv/secure?url=http://trkvz-live.ercdn.net/atvhd/atvhd.m3u8&'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=response.read()
response.close()
match=re.compile('url":"(.*?)"').findall(link)
for m3u8 in match:
    m3u8=m3u8.replace('\u0026','&')
    print m3u8
    req = urllib2.Request(m3u8)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    link=response.read()
    response.close()
    line=link
    line=line.replace('atvhd_','http://trkvz-live.ercdn.net/atvhd/atvhd_')
    print line
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
import urllib.request

res = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.2")
page = res.read()
```

Comment: m3u8 is locked to IP address if I download I can only watch other person can't watch so I made php user clicks the php then python will trigger and  get's the m3u8 file but I have to request with his IP or m3u8 will not work